# Exterior power of a locally free sheaf twisted

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, exterior-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth projective scheme and $F$ a locally free sheaf of $\text{rank}(F) = r$ and $L$ a line bundle on $X$.

This week here during a seminar, there was heated discussion about a result. The person who was presenting the seminar said:

\begin{equation}
(1) \bigwedge ^{i}(F \otimes L) \simeq (\bigwedge^{i} F) \otimes L 
\end{equation}

For me, the correct one is:

\begin{equation}
(2) \bigwedge ^{i}(F \otimes L) \simeq (\bigwedge^{i} F )\otimes( L^{\otimes i} )
\end{equation}

In addition, the other people who attended this seminar agreed with isomorphism (1).

I have tried to argue that correct isomorphism is (2), but, I am told that the correct is isomorphism (1), because line bundles do not "see" the exterior power in this case. To me this is not true.

**Only I**, not agreeing with isormorphism (1), humbly come to this forum to ask: Is the isomorphism (1) really correct?

If not, how can I rigorously prove that ismorphism (2) is correct?

**Remark**: I started studying these tools a little while ago, getting ready for the master's degree, so I think because I am still a graduate student, they didn't believe my argument.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are correct. Why not give them a counter example first? Take $F=O\oplus O$. Then $F\otimes L=L\oplus L$ and thus its second exterior is $L^2$, whereas in (1), you would have got $L$, which is wrong.

Comment: @Mohan. Thank you very much....thanks...Now, for me, it is a matter of honor to show isomorphism (2) in the hand. At that moment, I didn't even think of showing a counterexample. Again, thank you very much. If I cannot show isomorphism, I will look for the demonstration in some reference.

Comment: They said it is a trivial result and I would find it in any basic book on the subject. I am looking for and so far I have not found this basic result.

Comment: @Mohan. I can see the injectivity of (2).How can I show that this morphism is surjective? Can you give me an idea? thank you very much.

Comment: Assuming that you have defined the natural map from the left to the right, your injectivity should imply injectivity restricted to any point. But restricted to a point, both sides are vector spaces of the same dimension and thus injectivity implies surjectivity. Surjectivity restricted to all points imply surjectivity of the original map.

Comment: @Mohan. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear colleagues Mohan and Emanuell. Could you tell me how this morphism is defined? I was also interested in this morphism which is a useful tool. Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: @AllainJF. I'm not mature yet on this subject to the point of posting a correct answer. Surely another user will be able to help you better than me. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: For those wondering what the morphism is, write down the only thing you could ever write down. It will be correct. Proving it will be a good exercise. (Obvious hint: write down what a local section looks like on both sides.)